# How to style a <div> so that it has no effect?

Tags: css

Is it possible to style a div so that it has no effect on the layout?
(as if the tag wasn't present in the html)

The reason I ask is that I am planning on creating a workaround for css3 multiple column layout on ie7, ie8 & ie9.

On these versions of ie, the columns will be implemented using vertical divs. However, on browsers that support css3 columns, I would like these divs to have zero effect (however on ie, I will override this to create columns). Can I create a css class that does this?

e.g.

```
<div class="noeffect">
<div class="item">item1</div>
<div class="item">item2</div>
</div>

<div class="noeffect">
<div class="item">item3</div>
<div class="item">item4</div>
</div>

<div class="noeffect">
<div class="item">item5</div>
<div class="item">item6</div>
</div>
```

So on IE 'noeffect' could be overridden to display 3 columns, however on other browsers, multiple column layout could be used to display 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 columns.

Comment: You should look at [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I have had a look at that. I am wondering what is possible without JS though.

Comment: How about [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)?

Comment: simply `display:none`

Comment: Vucko - yes, if there's no way to do it with CSS, conditional comments around every div tag in the HTML may be the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE7, IE8 and IE9 support what are known as [***conditional comments***](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). These allow you to only include specific content when the IE browser matches the condition.

### Internet Explorer's Conditional Comments

*Note that these were removed in IE11 and will not render even when immitating older versions of IE through IE11's developer tools.*

In your case, we can use `if lte IE 9` to match any version of IE less than or equal to (`lte`) IE 9 to load an IE-specific stylesheet:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IE-Specific-CSS.css">
<![endif]-->
```

This stylesheet would then overwrite the content in your regular CSS file. Your `head` element would end up looking something like this:

```
<head>
    <title>...</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Regular-CSS.css">
    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="IE-Specific-CSS.css">
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

All browsers which are not versions of IE less than or equal to IE9 would only load the `Regular-CSS.css` file, whereas IE9 and lower would load both `Regular-CSS.css` and `IE-Specific-CSS.css`. It's then down to [**specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to allow the IE-specific CSS declarations to override the other CSS file's declarations.

### Example CSS

```css
/* Regular-CSS.css */
div.noeffect {
    background: #f00;    /* Red background */
}
```

```css
/* IE-Specific-CSS.css */
div.noeffect {
    background: #0f0;    /* Green background only on IE9 and lower */
}
```

The above two selectors (`div.noeffect`) have the same *specificity* (linked above), so as long as our IE-specific CSS document was loaded *after* our regular CSS document, the IE-specific CSS would override the regular one.

### Only Rendering the `div` Elements in IE9 or Lower

If you want those `div` elements to only appear on IE9 or lower you can just wrap the conditional comments around each `div` tag:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<div class="noeffect">
<![endif]-->
    <div class="item">item1</div>
    <div class="item">item2</div>
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
</div>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<div class="noeffect">
<![endif]-->
    <div class="item">item3</div>
...
```

Comment: This is absolutely the way you target IE with fixes.

Comment: Yes, I definitely want to use these. However, I don't want the <div> tags (which will be used by the IE css) to affect the layout in none IE browsers.

Comment: @PaulS you can set `div.noeffect` to `display: none` in the regular CSS file, and override that in the IE-specific CSS file.

Comment: I still want to display the items in both browsers. display:none will hide the items. I want the effect to be as if the div tag didn't exist, not hiding everything inside it.

Comment: @JamesDonnely - yes, it looks like conditionals around the div classes may be the best option. The last sentence and example may be the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the HTML, the CSS will see it and consider it in the cascade. `display:none` will hide the div and everything in it.

If you use James Donnelly's conditional stylesheet suggestion, then yes, it is possible to completely ignore `.noeffect` in terms of rules by having all rules involving the child div's mention `.item`. Any reference to a classless `div` could potentially pick up `.noeffect`.

Structure is harder than style: css cannot change the page's HTML hierarchy. It will not prevent `.noeffect` from being the parent of `.item`, nor will it make all the `.item`'s siblings.

Answer (score -2):

The way you take an element completely out of the flow and layout is to set its display property to “none.”

```
div.noeffect {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this hides the items inside, so it does have a very significant effect.